# Retrieving item with multiple tags appended

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I want to get a post where it matches multiple tags. 

I can get all of the tags per post but not the other way around

Here is my schema

```
Post: 
POST_ID,POST_BODY
```

Then I have a

```
Tag table: 
TAG_ID, TAG_NAME
```

I then have a

```
PT table: 
PT_POSTID, PT_TAGID
```

It's a one to many relationship from post to tags. I can get get all of posts where TAG_ID = 1
But how do I get a post where it has both tagid =1 and tag=2  and so forth?

Comment: Look up "relational division" for some ideas. That would also help you to better frame if you want posts that *only* have tags 1 and 2, or all posts that include those (and possibly others)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SELECT * 
FROM PT
GROUP BY PT_POSTID

Is this what your asking for or did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: Close but not what I am looking for.   I want it where if I select EG. Tag_ID = 41 and TAG_ID = 42. I would be displayed with only the post that matches those id's